# freebsd iso install on KVM - timer freezes

Tags: debian, freebsd, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu

Trying to boot freebsd iso on KVM/libvirt [debian host]

Timer shows: 10 sometimes is 9 or even 7. and that's it, count down stops..
[Found](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/109436/) some information that it's a bug with newest qemu and my kernel version.

iso used is: amd64. machine has 2cpu physical cpu's with 4 cores.

> uname -a
>       Linux ns387352.ovh.net 2.6.38.2-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 #2 SMP Thu Aug 25 16:43:23 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux

kernel upgrade would be real pain on this damned hosting..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgraded kernel and it works. Strange issue.

Comment: _Which_ kernel?

Comment: well this was like year ago, i don't even remember.